# Are data sms ports in Android an actual hardware feature?

Tags: android

I've read that in Android a data sms can be sent to a specific port, say port 8901. Are there a set of predefined port numbers that can be used, or is the concept of "ports" a software specific notion?

I have not found any information on it yet, so I'm thinking that the port number more or less works like a filter of sorts.

## Questions:

- Are ports a hardware or software implementation?
- Are the ports used only as a manner of filtering through incoming messages?
- Are there any preferences as to what port I should use when transferring data from one Android device to another?
- Are there any pitfalls regarding ports that I'd do wise to steer away from?
- Are there any security details I should know about before using ports?

The reason that I want to use ports is that the app I am developing will have to trade information with other devices. I do not want these messages to appear in the message inbox, so normal sms messages are not a possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are ports a hardware or software implementation?

Software.

> Are the ports used only as a manner of filtering through incoming messages?

You could say that, yeah.

> Are there any preferences as to what port I should use when transferring data from one Android device to another?

I know 8901 is used for some voice mail systems' device data updates. I only mention that one in particular because I often see it as the port used in examples. The ports used and their purposes are, of course, going to vary from system to system. You just need to check if the data you receive is what you want, and otherwise ignore it. It's completely possible for multiple apps to use the same port.

> Are there any pitfalls regarding ports that I'd do wise to steer away from?

None that I can think of. It's basically regular old SMS, just in a different format.

> Are there any security details I should know about before using ports?

No more than with regular SMS. It's obviously not a secure protocol, and any app listening can get your messages. Whether it'll know what to do with them, or how to interpret them, is another story. I would mention that an app can listen on all ports, and therefore get every incoming data SMS, or another app could just so happen to be using the same port as yours. If that concerns you, make sure you implement your own sort of encryption or obfuscation.